# What is the best method to link to a related subset of another table/list within a List Column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How would I go about, within the List Column "Updates", linking to or otherwise returning...

| Issue Key | Issue Title | Updates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282 | SABER Project | table_of_updates_to_282 |
| 179 | Change turbo air intake housing | table_of_updates_to_179 |
| 278 | DAT report and ROI | table_of_updates_to_278 |
| 263 | DAT to be Program of Record? | table_of_updates_to_263 |
| 204 | Maximum MDE Power Level increase to 4300 kW | table_of_updates_to_204 |

....the related portion of the table below?

| Issue Key | Date Update | Update Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282 | 9/11/2023 | Jake, Here is the latest topology map for FRC MCMS. |
| 282 | 9/7/2023 | Paul - Here is the PowerPoint I created. It should be good as a job aid for anyone in the networking realm to understand. |
| 278 | 11/2/2022 | Dave, Full pdf version attached. |
| 278 | 11/1/2022 | Dave – Please see attached 2022 FRC ROI Report. |
| 278 | 10/31/2022 | Tim - Go ahead and accept all changes and delete all comments. Then, create a pdf. |

Comment: Try using [SharePoint lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) for relationship between 2 lists. Let me know if it helps.